# Export mysql database / mysql tables in json format through command line OR PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have big information table. I want to export it in json format for some other purpose. I could export in xml format using the below command.

`mysql -u root -p --xml -e "SELECT * FROM db_name.tbl_name" > d:\export.xml`

I tried something like the below for json format. 
`mysql -u root -p --json -e "SELECT * FROM db_name.tbl_name" > d:\export.json`

I got the error message `unknown option '--json'`

**PS:** I could not able to use any third party application like PHPMyadmin / workbench / SQLyog due to large size of table.

It would be greatly appreciated if you help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**mysql cannot output directly in json format**

so you have two options:

1. export in XML the use a tool to convert from XML to JSON (a tool that can deal with large tables of course)
2. write a small script (for example in PHP) that fetch the data from the DB and writes it to file in JSON

**Important note:**

If you choose option nr. (2) you may have trouble loading the whole table data, converting to JSON and saving to file in a single "atomic" step **if you have a lot of records**.

However you may break the task into steps.

Basically a table turned into a JSON is an array of objects, each object representing a single record.

1. Open a connection to the db
2. Start writing the output file and open the array by writing an open square bracket `[`
3. Execute your query fetching *n* ( 1 < n < 1000 ) record at time. (In order to do that you have to `SORT` the table by any field -ex. `id`- and use the `LIMIT` clause)
4. Convert each record with `json_econde`, write the string to file, write a comma `,` unless you have written the last record.
5. Back to **3** until you reach the last record.
6. Write a closing square bracket to file `]` (closing the array).
7. Close the file and the db connection

This would require a little more coding but it's not rocket science.

...and maybe you find something online that already does that.

**Update:**

A script that fetch the data from the DB and writes it to file in JSON can be found here on GitHub: [Dump-table-to-JSON](https://github.com/paolobertani/Dump-table-to-JSON) (last updated 2016).

Comment: I can write PHP script. But the amount of data is too large. So the script unable to complete the process.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I will go with your answer if I didn't find any other options.

Comment: @Naga see my update for a ready to use script that fetch the data from the DB and writes it to file in JSON format

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mysql Shell to directly out put to JSON.

```
echo "[Your SQL query]" | mysqlsh --sql --result-format=json --uri=[username]@localhost/[schema_name]
```