# Generate JSON Object for Mysql Tier Table (PHP)

Tags: php, html, mysql, json

Straight to point i have 3 tables like following -

**QTY Types Table**

```
--------------------
| ID  |  QTY types |
|  1  |  1         |
|  2  |  2-4       |
|  3  |  5-9       |
|  4  |  10-24     |
|  5  |  25+       |
--------------------
```

**Poster Size Table**

```
-----------------------
| ID  |  Poster Size  |
+-----+---------------+
|  1  |  A4           |
|  2  |  A3           |
|  3  |  A2           |
|  4  |  A1           |
|  5  |  A0           |
-----------------------
```

**Price table (based on Qty ID- column title)**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| qty_id_1  |  qty_id_2  |  qty_id_3  |  qty_id_4  |  qty_id_5  |  poster_size |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------+
|     4     |    3.5     |   2.75     |   3.25     |         3  |            1 |
|     6     |    5.5     |      4     |   4.75     |       4.5  |            2 |
|    12     |    9.5     |    6.5     |    8.5     |         8  |            3 |
|    18     |     16     |   10.5     |     14     |      12.5  |            4 |
|    34     |     33     |     25     |     31     |        28  |            5 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I just wanted to Generate Price According to User Input for example if user selects `Qty.id=2 Poster_size.id=3` so answer will be **$9.5**.

All of this data are static so after that i just wanted to generate JSON file 
using `fwrite (php)` something like this

```
    {
        "qty_1":{
            "poster_size_1":[
                {
                    "price":4
                }
            ],
            "poster_size_2":[
                {
                    "price":6
                }
            ],
            "poster_size_3":[
                {
                    "price":12
                }
            ],
            "poster_size_4":[
                {
                    "price":18
                }
            ],
            "poster_size_5":[
                {
                    "price":34
                }
            ]
        },
        "qty_2":{
            "poster_size_1":[
                {
                    "price":3.5
                }
            ],
            "poster_size_2":[
                {
                    "price":5.5
                }
            ],
            "poster_size_3":[
                {
                    "price":9.5
                }
            ],
            "poster_size_4":[
                {
                    "price":16
                }
            ],
            "poster_size_5":[
                {
                    "price":33
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

By this i can easily access `obj.qty_1.poster_size_3.price` as **$9.5**.

How can i populate JSON file like this or is there any alternate way to populate different JSON structure to get my required data. (im new to JSON objects)

Help Appreciated | Thanks in Advance

[Please Check this my sample PHP file to generate JSON](https://gist.github.com/joeljerushan/686454b52688f3d4d3b5319cc3b68d3c)

Comment: yest but its not generating json array like i wished .. hope you understand my situation with retrieving large amount of data

Comment: https://gist.github.com/joeljerushan/686454b52688f3d4d3b5319cc3b68d3c 

here this is sample but this is not what i wanted i just wanted to nest 3 tables data to one Object like i asked in question ..

Comment: I've Just got an idea if i create a JSON object like i mentioned in question it will help to get prices from. that's why i didn;t have a code to show you; but i attempt to create a json file like above comment .. (gist file)

Comment: Have you tried to echo json_encode() ? Before doing it, are you sure that your sql queries are correct and the arrays are building properly? do step by step debugging.

Comment: It is my opinion that doing this task "the right way" would mean using MYSQL to its fullest and making a single query call with JOINs.  You will need to return a resultset like [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5563bc671a21949b4dd44e2134734e82143f04f7) and then building the desired array then converting to json will be a snap.  If you are unable to write such a query, then you may ask for help, but we will be better equipped (and can test our work / provide a sqlfiddle) if you post an sql export of the necessary tables.

Comment: i checked your snippet its fine if i had a table like that but in my scenario check **Price table** i have  price table separated that's not only one i have more than 50 price tables for different products. that;s why im trying to generate some thing like my example JSON

Comment: or better can you help me to merge and create new table like your sample code and seed it with my current tables ?

Answer (score 1):

explain like this a array like json.

```
$arr = array(
  'qty_1' => array(
    "poster_size_1" => array(
      "price" => 4
    ),
  'qty_2' => array(
    'key' => 'value',
    'key2' => array(
       value, value2
    )
  )
);
```

this array will make

```
{"qty_1": {"poster_size_1" : {"price": 4}}} blabla...
```

Comment: This  low-quality answer may actually confuse the OP about proper array structure since the first subarray is different from the second.  Please improve or delete.

Comment: This one is maybe Low Quality but this did a trick and helpful to understand how to populate object with PHP thank you

Answer (score 0):

create an array / Object that the way you want json and use `json_encode()` function to convert array to json then write into a file.

Comment: yest could you please explain me how to generate JSON object like my need with PHP (its nested JSON Object but using QTY table id as top level object)

Comment: for nested JSON, create multi dimensional array / object. You may refer this  link<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102747/export-mysql-database-mysql-tables-in-json-format-through-command-line-or-php>. But it was created different purpose. Still it will help you to use the logic and some php codes.

Comment: Have you tried to echo json_encode() ? Before doing it, are you sure that your sql queries are correct and the arrays are building properly? do step by step debugging.